# Device number in stat command output

Tags: linux

```
  stat test.log 
  File: `test.log'
  Size: 573         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 804h/2052d  Inode: 7091301     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1001/   abc)   Gid: ( 1001/   abc)
Access: 2010-11-29 17:56:22.000000000 -0800
Modify: 2010-11-29 17:56:22.000000000 -0800
Change: 2010-11-29 17:56:22.000000000 -0800
```

In the stat o/p above what does the ***Device*** entry signify ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
# stat tool
  File: `tool'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 671689      Links: 3

# ls -l /dev/sda*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 2010-08-16 14:43 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 2010-08-16 14:43 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 2 2010-08-16 14:43 /dev/sda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 5 2010-08-16 14:43 /dev/sda5
```

In the example, 'tool' (801h) is in `/dev/sda1` (major device number is 8, minor device number is 1). That's the first partition in `/dev/sda`.

Comment: Just to clarify; the 8 only happens to correspond without conversion because it's below 10, otherwise if you had something like fe01h you would convert "fe" from hex to dec and get "254".

Comment: It should be added, that the `/2049d` is the same value in decimal.

Comment: Also: If one mounts the whole disk, without a partition table, would `sda` be `800h` then?

Comment: It sure would be interesting to know what the numbers 8 and 1 mean in this context.

Comment: Some filesystems such as btrfs do not compose the filesystem's device number from the device numbers of the underlying device(s) but create a new, virtual device number, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345220/btrfs-how-to-get-real-device-id.

Answer (score 21):

It's the major and minor device number combined into one value (in hex and decimal) of the device on which the file resides.

For your example, `804h` is major device 8, minor device 4. if you run `df .` while you're in the directory where that file is, you'll get the device name such as `/dev/sda1`. If you were to then do `ls -al /dev/sda1`, it would show you the device numbers. Here's an example:

```
pax$ stat newfile # note device 801h, hex 801 = 2049 decimal
  File: 'newfile'
  Size: 2097152     Blocks: 4096       IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 2888080     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/     pax)   Gid: ( 1000/     pax)
Access: 2010-11-29 07:32:22.011271661 +0800
Modify: 2010-08-30 15:43:14.286796827 +0800
Change: 2010-08-30 15:43:14.286796827 +0800

pax$ df . # to get current device mount
Filesystem           1K-blocks Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1            470301088 182471788 263939332  41% /

pax$ ls -al /dev/sda1 # to get major/minor = 8/1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 2010-11-30 07:02 /dev/sda1
```

Comment: Does it mean that when the Device value is in hex format, major and minor version are always separated with a 0 (zero)?

Comment: @Simon, major and minor numbers are eight bits each so, if major is `17` and minor is `35`, you'll get `1123h`: `17 == 11h` and `35 == 23h`. So the `0` is only between them if the minor number is less than `16 == 10h`.

Comment: For `btrfs` filesystems, `stat` reports non-existing device numbers, e.g. `65h/101d` but `ls -l /dev | grep "^b" | fgrep 101 | wc -l` says `0`. According to an answer on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345220/btrfs-how-to-get-real-device-id , device numbers of filesystems do not have to correspond to device numbers of the underlying devices.

Answer (score 17):

From `man 2 stat`:

> The st_dev field describes the device on which this file resides. (The
> major(3) and minor(3) macros may be useful to decompose the device ID
> in this field.)

These macros are not defined by POSIX, but implemented in glibc, in [`sysmacros.h`](https://github.com/jeremie-koenig/glibc/blob/master-beware-rebase/sysdeps/generic/sys/sysmacros.h). The C implementation of these macros is:

```
#define major(dev) ((int)(((unsigned int) (dev) >> 8) & 0xff))
#define minor(dev) ((int)((dev) & 0xff))
```

What you can easily do in e.g. Python then is

```py
>>> import os
>>> minor = int(os.stat("/lib").st_dev & 0xff)
>>> major = int(os.stat("/lib").st_dev >> 8 & 0xff)
>>> major, minor
(8, 1)
```

The major ID identifies the device driver, the minor ID encodes the physical disk as well as the partition. In case of SCSI disks, the major ID is always 8. Partitions on the first disk have a minor ID between 1 and 15. Partitions on the second disk have a minor ID between 17 and 31, and so on.

Reference: https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/devices.txt

Hence,

```
>>> major, minor
(8, 1)
```

means `sda1`: `sd` (major 8 → SCSI), `a1` (minor 1 → first disk, first partition).

Comment: It appears that the device number may not always be 2 bytes. I'm running ZFSOnLinux and I see only just `16h/22d`, which doesn't actually tell me anything, since I can't find a 22 major device nor a 22 minor device.

Answer (score 2):

The stat command is simply a frontend to the stat() system call.

From the stat(2) manual page (`man 2 stat`)

> The st_dev field describes the device
>   on which this file resides.  (The
>   major(3) and minor(3) macros may be
>   useful to decompose the device ID in
>   this field.)

From the 0804 hex notation you get major=8 (/dev/sd*) minor=4. i.e. /dev/sda4

Comment: Your mapping of major/minor number => drive/partition isn't *guaranteed* to be true, but there's no reason for the kernel to change it so you can probably rely on it

Comment: @Paul Betts, if the major/minor mapping is not true, then what are the implications of that on `stat` o/p and otherwise. Can you elaborate on your comment please ?

Comment: So, think of "major/minor" as "driver/device instance", it really has to do more with PnP / kernel driver <=> device mapping, than anything storage subsystem specific

Comment: For a classical hard disk setup, can't we say that the major ID corresponds to the 'physical disk' while the minor ID corresponds to the partition? Where would that be documented?

Comment: The partitions of NVMe-attached disks, at least on my mainboard, get consecutive minors across disks (SSDs), sharing the same major.

Comment: "For a classical hard disk setup" yes, probably.  For everything else... nvme, sas, raid, zfs, btrfs, lvm, tmpfs, procfs, sysfs and everything else newer than 1980's style "classical hard disk setup", no.