# What does syscall.Stat_t.Dev map to?

Tags: unix, go

Golang's `syscall.Stat_t` has a `Dev` field, which I assume identifies the disk/device, see https://golang.org/src/syscall/ztypes_linux_amd64.go?s=1392:1688#L91

For example, for a `syscall.Stat_t` structure mapping to a file on my disk, `Dev` has value `51713`; my question is: is that ID purely internal to Go? Or does it map to some OS ID (in which case, which one, and how can I see it with standard Unix CLI tools?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`syscall.Stat_t.Dev` represents the ID of device on which the given file resides. So it's not internal to Go. You can find it using `stat` command like,

```
stat --format=%d <filename>
```

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309882/device-number-in-stat-command-output) for more about device numbers.