# Device number vs major/minor number in stat output

Tags: linux

I ran the command `stat /dev/sda` and got the following output:

```
  File: '/dev/sda'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   block special file
Device: 6h/6d   Inode: 11511       Links: 1     Device type: 8,0
Access: (0660/brw-rw----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    6/    disk)
Access: 2017-08-04 10:25:29.422010000 -0400
Modify: 2017-07-29 07:48:23.800000000 -0400
Change: 2017-07-29 07:48:23.800000000 -0400
 Birth: -
```

I'm confused about what `device: 6h/6d` and `device type: 8,0` mean.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309882/device-number-in-stat-command-output), `device: 6h/6d` is supposed to be the major/minor numbers in hex and decimal (minor number missing in this case?) but I'm pretty sure major/minor are given by `Device type: 8,0`. If so what does `device: 6h/6d` mean?

Comment: Read the linked answers again.  6 is the number of the device on which the *file* `/dev/sda` resides.  Remember that devices are files, every file lives on a filesystem, and every filesystem is (in principle) backed by a device.  Look at what happens when you run stat on a regular file: you still have an entry in the Device field.  For instance, if /dev/sdb6 is mounted on /foo, and you stat /foo/bar, you'll see the device number of /dev/sdb6 in the Device field.

Comment: So in this case it's the "device" corresponding to the `/dev` filesystem.  This may not be a real device, if you are using `devtmpfs` or similar, but something has to go in that field.

Comment: Thanks that helps. So these devices numbers are **not** documented in [here](https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/devices.txt).

Comment: Well, partly; it's major 0 minor 6, and major 0 is shown as "unnamed devices" for non-device mounts.  Which is the case if you're using a virtual filesystem for /dev, as most modern distributions do.

Comment: Cool. Very much appreciated!